# Why is the output wrong when using neat to generate Media queries

Tags: css, sass, pug, bourbon, neat

Okay so I have a project which I use SASS to compile to CSS using gulp, and I use Bourbon and Neat for the grid system. I find it weird the following is not already responsive.

Jade Template:

```
article.fleet
        .container
            .row
                .image-container
                    img(src="images/image.svg")
                .text-container
                    p text
```

SASS for it

```
.container
  +outer-container
  p
    color: #493F3F
    line-height: $font-size-base * $line-height-lg
    article.story
        height: 450px
        p
            +span-columns(6)
```

And then i try to test by setting the breakpoint with `$mobile: @mixin new-breakpoint(max-width 480px 4)`

I found out when I use `@include media($mobile)` the output of the compiled CSS is like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: (+max-width) 480px 4) {
      section.hero h1 {
        font-size: 18px; }
```

Why does it output `(min-width: (+max-width) 480px 4)` ... is there something wrong with neat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your breakpoint wrong.
The new-breakpoint mixin do not need the **@mixin** declaration. So you have to change it to:

```
$mobile: new-breakpoint(max-width 480px 4);
```

I don't try it in your code, but I think it works.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. I was too careless about that. haha